# Changing CoreNLP settings at runtime

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm using Stanford CoreNLP pipeline, and I wonder whether there is a way to edit basic settings without restarting the whole tool (avoiding the reload of the models).

Now I have:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("tokenize.whitespace", "true");
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, ...");
StanfordCoreNLP stanfordPipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
```

I'd like to change the `tokenize.whitespace` setting on the fly, without restarting everything. Is it possible?

Comment: One could use `StanfordCoreNLP.getExistingAnnotator("tokenize")` to get the actual one Annotator.  In a unit testing environment, one could set props by using reflection because it is not directly accessible.  However, this path I have described points out how something like this really is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only create a new instance of StanfordCoreNLP with other properties; all common annotators and their models won't be reloaded, because StanfordCoreNLP uses static AnnotatorPool (see [src code](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP.java), line 103), where AnnotatorPool is:

> An object for keeping track of Annotators. Typical use is to allow
> multiple  pipelines to share any Annotators in common.
>
> For example, if multiple pipelines exist, and they both need a
> ParserAnnotator, it would be bad to load two such Annotators into
> memory.  Instead, an AnnotatorPool will only create one Annotator
> and allow both pipelines to share it.

(taken from [javadoc](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/AnnotatorPool.java))